# Retrieve Map from Firebase Firestore using REST API on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve maps values from a Firebase Firestore JSON file. So far I've been able to get any field I wanted but I'm having trouble with maps since they are so nested.
Here you can see an image of the JSON.
[image: JSON File]

And here you can see as text.

```
"user_metrics": {
  "arrayValue": {
    "values": [
      {
        "mapValue": {
          "fields": {
            "point1": {
              "integerValue": "0"
            },
            "point2": {
              "integerValue": "0"
            },
            "metricDescription": {
              "stringValue": "Distanza Pupillare"
            },
            "metricResult": {
              "doubleValue": 6.27
            },
            "metricDescriptionEn": {
              "stringValue": "Distance between pupils"
            },
            "metricTitle": {
              "stringValue": "DBP"
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

And I'm decoding it as follows:

```
struct SessionResponse : Codable {
let sessions : [Session_Struct]

private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case sessions = "documents"
}
```

}

struct SessionStringValue : Codable {
let value : String

```
private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case value = "stringValue"
}
```

}

struct Session_Struct : Codable {
let is_first_session : Bool
let device : String
let glassesRefs : [String]
let ref_catalogo : String
let total_time : Double
let data_inizio_sessione : String
let data_fine_user_session : String
let device_id : String
let lineaRefs : [String]
let modelRefs : [String]
let user_metrics : [String]

```
private enum SessionKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case fields
}

private enum FieldKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case is_first_session
    case device
    case glassesRefs
    case ref_catalogo
    case total_time
    case data_inizio_sessione
    case data_fine_user_session
    case device_id
    case lineaRefs
    case modelRefs
    case user_metrics
}

// MARK: - Total Time
struct TotalTime: Codable {
    let doubleValue: Double
}

// MARK: - First Session
struct FirstSession: Codable {
    let booleanValue: Bool
}

// MARK: - ListaRefsSizes
struct MapMetrics: Codable {
    let arrayValue: MetricsArrayValue
}

// MARK: - ArrayValue
struct MetricsArrayValue: Codable {
    let values: [ValueMetric]
}

// MARK: - ArrayValue
struct ValueMetric: Codable {
    let mapValue : MapValue
}


// MARK: - ListaRefsSizes
struct ListaRefsGlasses: Codable {
    let arrayValue: ArrayValue
}

// MARK: - ArrayValue
struct ArrayValue: Codable {
    let values: [Value]
}

// MARK: - Value
struct Value: Codable {
    let stringValue: String
}

// MARK: - Value
struct MapValue: Codable {
    let mapValue: String
}

// MARK: - Value
struct ReferenceValue: Codable {
    let referenceValue: String
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: SessionKeys.self)
    
    let fieldContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: FieldKeys.self, forKey: .fields)
    
    is_first_session = try fieldContainer.decode(FirstSession.self, forKey: .is_first_session).booleanValue
    device = try fieldContainer.decode(SessionStringValue.self, forKey: .device).value
    ref_catalogo = try fieldContainer.decode(ReferenceValue.self, forKey: .ref_catalogo).referenceValue
    total_time = try fieldContainer.decode(TotalTime.self, forKey: .total_time).doubleValue
    data_inizio_sessione = try fieldContainer.decode(SessionStringValue.self, forKey: .data_inizio_sessione).value
    data_fine_user_session = try fieldContainer.decode(SessionStringValue.self, forKey: .data_fine_user_session).value
    device_id = try fieldContainer.decode(SessionStringValue.self, forKey: .device_id).value
    
    
    //Lists
    glassesRefs = try fieldContainer.decode(ListaRefsGlasses.self, forKey: .glassesRefs)
        .arrayValue.values.map{ $0.stringValue }
    
    lineaRefs = try fieldContainer.decode(ListaRefsGlasses.self, forKey: .lineaRefs)
        .arrayValue.values.map{ $0.stringValue }
    
    modelRefs = try fieldContainer.decode(ListaRefsGlasses.self, forKey: .modelRefs)
        .arrayValue.values.map{ $0.stringValue }
    
    user_metrics = try fieldContainer.decode(MapMetrics.self, forKey: .user_metrics)
        .arrayValue.values.map{ $0.mapValue } // <-- How to read this??
}
```

}

My issue is that I'm not being able to read the array inside the field "user_metrics". Any idea on how to achieve that? Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: copy then paste all your json data into `https://app.quicktype.io/`,
 it will generate all the correct structs for you, including your troublesome
 array inside the field "user_metrics". And you will learn how to do it for the next time you come across this structure.

Comment: I already tried that even with various configurations, but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let userMetrics: UserMetrics

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userMetrics = "user_metrics"
    }
}

// MARK: - UserMetrics
struct UserMetrics: Codable {
    let arrayValue: ArrayValue
}

// MARK: - ArrayValue
struct ArrayValue: Codable {
    let values: [Value]
}

// MARK: - Value
struct Value: Codable {
    let mapValue: MapValue
}

// MARK: - MapValue
struct MapValue: Codable {
    let fields: Fields
}

// MARK: - Fields
struct Fields: Codable {
    let point1, point2: Point
    let metricDescription: Metric
    let metricResult: MetricResult
    let metricDescriptionEn, metricTitle: Metric
}

// MARK: - Metric
struct Metric: Codable {
    let stringValue: String
}

// MARK: - MetricResult
struct MetricResult: Codable {
    let doubleValue: Double
}

// MARK: - Point
struct Point: Codable {
    let integerValue: String
}
```

there is structure for your json
call the api request and get data to Welcome(renamed it as you want)

```
 func requestHTTP(urlString:String,completionHandler:@escaping(_ model:Welcome?,_ error:Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let requestUrl = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestUrl) { (data, httpUrlResponse, error) in
         if(error == nil && data != nil && data?.count != 0) {
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data!)
                completionHandler(response,nil)
            } catch {
                debugPrint("error")
                completionHandler(nil,error)
            }
         } else {
             completionHandler(nil,error)
         }
        }.resume()
            
    }
```

and your will get your data easily

```
func getDataOnController() {
        requestHTTP(urlString: "your url here") { model, error in
           if let model = model {
            let mapVlues = model.userMetrics.arrayValue.values.map({$0.mapValue})
            print(mapVlues)
            print(mapVlues.count)
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, good, but how do I make it work in the init method? I mean, I need a line of code like this "user_metrics = try fieldContainer.decode(MapMetrics.self, forKey: .user_metrics)
        .arrayValue.values.map{ $0.mapValue } // <-- How to read this??", right? But I can't figure out what to put in there.

Comment: edited my answer just check out the method getDataOnController()